# Get Middleware Name In Laravel Controller

Tags: php, laravel, middleware

I am facing a problem in my application. 
Let there is two middleware
1)User
2)Admin 
Is it possible to get which middleware I authenticated in my controller? 
I am using Laravel 5.4.
Here is my route declaration

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'user'], function () {
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:api']], function () {
        Route::post('shop/store', 'ApiShopController@shopStore');
        Route::post('shop/update', 'ApiShopController@shopUpdate');
    });
});
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:admin-api']], function () {
        Route::post('shop/store', 'ApiShopController@shopStore');
        Route::post('shop/update', 'ApiShopController@shopUpdate');
    });
});
```

Here is my midlleware declaration

```
'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],
        'admin-api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],
]
```

Comment: Could you please show your route declaration and the usage of the middlewares?

Comment: @AdreAstrian I am updated my answer please check

Comment: How about using different controllers and/or methods for the two middlewares?

Comment: @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin No I want to use same controller. is it possible? My route will be different but controller will be same

Comment: @zayedhassan, your route declaration is exactly the same in both cases. So If I take the order of the code shown here the `auth:admin-api` declaration will override the `auth:api` declaration! Using a different middleware for a `api/admin/shop/store` route won't give you two paths, right?

Comment: @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin sorry for my mistake. I have updated my route. Please take a look

Answer (score 1):

You should use Auth::guard('role')

Answer (score 0):

You could include this in your Controller constructor to assign in the a middleware directly, for example like this:

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
    public function index()
    {
        return view('home');
    }
}
```

You could run this method in your controller aswell but I did not check it yet:

```
$middleware = $this->getMiddleware();
```

That should return the middleware in your controller

Answer (score 0):

if your application has two guards **'admin'** and **'user'** in your `config/auth.php`

```
...
'admin' => [
    'driver' => 'session',
    'provider' => 'admin',
],
'user' => [
    'driver' => 'session',
    'provider' => 'user',
],
```

, then you can get current guard

```
@if(Auth::guard('admin')->check())
    Hello {{Auth::guard('admin')->user()->name}}
@elseif(Auth::guard('user')->check())
    Hello {{Auth::guard('user')->user()->name}}
@endif
```

Comment: so every time I have to use if, else. Does not have any other option?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding about middleware is to help you do a filter on who you allow access a particular route/resources or intercept the request before it hits your resources in your Laravel app and that is why it is placed right during routes declaration or when the constructor is *constructed*; Check [Middleware Introduction](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/middleware#introduction)

However, for your case I would reconstruct my route declaration to look like this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:api']], function () {
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'user'], function () {
        Route::post('shop/store', 'ApiShopController@shopStore');
        Route::post('shop/update', 'ApiShopController@shopUpdate');
    });
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:admin-api']], function () {
        Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
            Route::post('shop/store', 'ApiShopController@shopStore');
            Route::post('shop/update', 'ApiShopController@shopUpdate');
        });
    });
});
```

My observation though is that the call to `user/shop/store` for example will be hitting `shopStore` method in ApiShopController that `admin/shop/store` will it.

I advice that you either separate the methods for that each routes are meant to work on or you don't need middleware, since you'll be needing `if` conditions to be checking stuffs that your middleware would have done for you or you use different controllers for each middleware group.

> PS: Let me know if there is something I missed about your question.

Answer (score 0):

The config has what is currently the default guard. If you used the `auth` middleware than which ever guard did the authenticating is set as the current default:

```
config('auth.defaults.guard'); 

Auth::getDefaultDriver();
```